# How to get the value in English from a momentjs object when the locale is set to another language?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Firstly, I'm using the bootstrap datetimepicker (http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) which runs on Momentjs.

My app is multi-lingual, and includes Asian languages such as Japanese, Chinese, and Arabic. When the locale is set into other languages sometimes the format (such as am/pm) of the value will include asian characters. This causes issues when I want to save the value into the my database and recall it later.

My code looks like this:

```
$('#bookingTime').datetimepicker({
    "format": 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A', 
    locale: " << The locale I'm setting >> ",
    stepping: 30,
    minDate: moment().millisecond(0).second(0).minute(0).hour(0),
    maxDate: new Date(new Date().setYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)),
  });
});
```

Currently I'm getting the data from the object using the '_d' value on the moment object:

```
$('#bookingTime').data("DateTimePicker").date()._d.toString();
```

But I thought there must be a better, less 'greasy' way. 
How can the value in English from a moment object when the locale is set to another language?

Comment: Store the ISO date/time.

Comment: Don't use `_d` or other internal fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want to call:

```
$('#bookingTime').data("DateTimePicker").date().format()
```

This will give you the date formatted as ISO8601:

2016-03-18T15:55:48-05:00

This is probably the best way to store a date for future use, as it can be interpreted by any culture.

You could also use moment's formatting tokens to get a variety of other formats.

If you really want it in English, you can change the locale. I would probably copy it first to avoid unexpected side effects of that change on the initial date:

```
var a  = $('#bookingTime').data("DateTimePicker").date().clone();
a.locale('en');
a.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A');//the date with english AM/PM
```